# how to open multiple tabs, from the command line, in gnome-terminal v3.44.0 (ubuntu 22.04), while running one custom command on each tab?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, tabs

how to open multiple tabs, from the command line, in gnome-terminal v3.44.0 (ubuntu 22.04), while running one custom command on each tab?

every other question/answer I found have answers about using `-e` option that is denied in gnome-terminal v3.44.0 in ubuntu 22.04.

So, all the answers I tried failed...

How to make it work now???

(I also found nothing helpful to workaround it thru `qdbus`)

Answer (score 1):

I found that, if I use another terminal like xterm to try to create tabs in the gnome-terminal, it will always fail. But if I do that from inside gnome-terminal it works!

```
gnome-terminal -- \
  bash -c " \
   gnome-terminal --tab -t a -- bash -c \"echo $RANDOM;sleep 100\"; \
   gnome-terminal --tab -t b -- bash -c \"echo $RANDOM;sleep 100\"; \
   gnome-terminal --tab -t c -- bash -c \"echo $RANDOM;sleep 100\"; \
  "
```